# Quotient by maximal normal locally finite subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, maximal-subgroup

Any group contains a unique maximal normal locally finite subgroup (this is an exercise in Robinson, second edition, p. 436). Does the quotient by this subgroup have any notable properties?

**Edit**: what if the ambient group is periodic?

Comment: Well it has no nontrivial normal locally finite subgroups!

Comment: @DerekHolt right! I just added a more specific setting, which is the one I am interested in

Comment: I think there's nothing more to say. This quotient is the largest quotient with no nontrivial normal locally finite subgroup.